# fixing non-null String must be provided to a Text widget

Tags: arrays, json, flutter, dart

I'm quite new in flutter.
I am working on a quiz app and try to make every quiz has five questions
I faced some problems :

1- I don't want to repeat the same question in the same quiz.[my quiz also start with question number one every time].

2- Every time it reaches my question number ten [which in array] nine my app crash.

NOTE: I'm using a JSON file to store my questions.

```
  int j = 1;
  int i = 1;
  var random_array;

  genrandomarray() {
var distinctIds = [];
var rand = new Random();
for (int i = 1;;) {
  distinctIds.add(rand.nextInt(10));
  random_array = distinctIds.toSet().toList();
  if (random_array.length < 10) {
    continue;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
print(random_array);
```

}

```
   setState(() {
  if (j < 5) {
    i = random_array[j];
    j++;
  } else {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => resultpage(marks: marks),
    ));
  }
 
  disableAnswer = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      genrandomarray() {
var rand = new Random();
```

make it choose random between questions

```
 var distinctIds = [i = rand.nextInt(10) + 1];
for (int i = 0;;) {
```

to not crash when it reach to 10 question

```
 distinctIds.add(rand.nextInt(10) + 1);
  random_array = distinctIds.toSet().toList();
  if (random_array.length < 10) {
    continue;
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
print(random_array);
```

}